# Taking text from div, inserting into text area, for editing, textarea doesn't show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is part of a simple notepad kind of widget and I am displaying the text on a div, then when I click the div, this should take the text from the div and insert it into a text area which I can then edit and then re-save. I decided to make it a php entry that I can edit/save/paginate. Anyway this is what I have:

The alerts are to track evaluation progress

```
function editLastDoing() {
var lastentry = $("#home-right-last-doing-tab").text();
alert(lastentry);
$("#home-right-last-doing-tab").text('');
$("textarea#last-doing").val(lastentry);
alert('tried to set text area html');
var currentvalue = $("textarea#last-doing").text();
alert(currentvalue);
document.getElementById('last-doing').style.display = "inline-block";
$("textarea#last-doing").css('display','inline-block');
alert('done');
}
```

I don't reach "done"

Comment: Can you post the `html` as well?

Comment: Why not just make the div `contentEditable` and scrap the textarea?

Comment: @j08691, I am not aware of that I'll read about real quick. I was also concerned about saving (php) but I'm not sure if php can go along with contentEditable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").on("click", function() {
        $("textarea").text($("div").text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4nz5yf5/2/

Comment: I'll have to try this, why the document.ready function? has to initiate?

Comment: Uhh I don't believe your answer is sufficient. I looks like you just duplicated his issue? Recheck your work - I don't want you to get unnecessary downvotes.    (**UPDATE** Nevermind, I reloaded the page and it worked - I thought it would because that is what I would have done :p but good work)

Comment: @janicehoplin - The document ready is to allow everything to load on the page before it tries to execute a function - See: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ - in short: "A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you."

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working for me. I have at least two differerent textareas, I try to differentiate between them by using $("textarea#id") but the web console says "getElementById(.... is null"